# My while loop works in the case of an incorrect input but I can't break out of it with a correct input

Tags: javascript

```
var proceed = false;
var userChoice;

function checkChoice(choice) {
    if (choice === "rock") {
        return ("Good luck!");
        proceed = true;
    }
    else if (choice === "paper") {
        return ("Good luck!");
        proceed = true;
    }
    else if (choice === "scissors") {
        return ("Good luck!");
        proceed = true;
    }
    else {
        return ("You did not select rock, paper or scissors!");
        proceed = false;
    }
}
while (proceed === false) {
    userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
    alert(checkChoice(userChoice));
}

//After this the computer makes its choice and it is compared with the users choice etc.
```

If the user inputs anyhting other than rock, paper or scissors then an alert box will say "You did not select rock, paper or scissors!" and then prompt the user to choose again which is perfect. But when the user does put in rock, paper or scissors correctly they get the expected "Good luck!" message followed by "undefined" and that's where the thing stops.

When the user puts in rock, paper or scissors it should come out of the while loop and execute the rest of the code, or that's the intention.

Comment: when the user will enter the value again?

Comment: You return from the function before you set the variable, so it will always be false.

Comment: Nothing written after return will be executed. Move the `proceed = ` before the returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are changing `proceed` after the `return`. After `return` no command is executed. So the `proceed` never changes its value to `true`. You have to change `proceed` value before `return`

Try

```
var proceed = false;
var userChoice;

function checkChoice(choice) {
if (choice === "rock") {
    proceed = true;
    return("Good luck!");

}
else if (choice === "paper") {
       proceed = true;
    return("Good luck!");

}
else if (choice === "scissors") {
    proceed = true;
    return("Good luck!");

}
else {
    proceed = false;
    return("You did not select rock, paper or scissors!");  

}
}

while (proceed === false) {
userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
alert(checkChoice(userChoice));
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6c4pX/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the variable `proceed` to true before returning the message.

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vinbtechdf/MNf4w/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it will be so much better.

```
function checkChoice(choice) {
switch (choice) {
    case "rock":
    case "paper":
    case "scissors":
        alert("Good luck!");
        return true;

    default:
       alert("You did not select rock, paper or scissors!");  
        return false;
}
}
function test() {
var proceed = false;
while (proceed === false) {
  userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");

  proceed = checkChoice(userChoice);
}
}
test();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MNf4w/2/)